Embedding diagram of $\phi=\mathrm{constant}$ surface in cylindrically symmetric spacetime
I'm trying to generate an embedding diagram for the $\phi=\mathrm{constant}$ hypersurface in a cylindrically symmetric spacetime. I think I'm supposed to start with $$A(p,z)dp^2+A(p,z)dz^2=dw^2+dp^2+dz^2$$ since $g_{pp}$ and $g_{zz}$ are the same in my case. This gets me to $$dw=\sqrt{(A(p,z)-1)(dp^2+dz^2)}$$ but I don't know how to proceed from here, since I know that there is no indefinite integral like there is in the Schwarzschild case.
